# How do I blink a sprite a few times before it disappears?

Tags: unity, c#, graphic-effects, timer

I need the 3d poop emoji model in the chest on the right to blink, visible-invisible-visible, several times:

[image]

This is a 3d gameObject oriented to face the camera, shaded with an unlit material.

I need the object to "blink/flash" to indicate that the item has been obtained. The object needs to be generated the moment the lid opens (done), stay unchanged until the lid pops all the way up (0.2 seconds), and flash 3 times during the 0.6 seconds the lid is up. The object is destroyed the moment the lid starts to come down again.

My code (blinking/flashing is not working)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemBox : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool disabled = false;
    private Animator anim;
    public GameObject item = null;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();        
        if (!disabled)
        {
            anim.Play("ItemBoxIdleState");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (!disabled && other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            anim.Play("ItemBoxGetItemState");
            GameObject itemClone = Instantiate(item, transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), Camera.main.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0,180,0));
            Blink(itemClone);
            Destroy(itemClone);
            disabled = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Blink(GameObject obj)
    {
        Renderer objRenderer = obj.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        objRenderer.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            objRenderer.enabled = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            objRenderer.enabled = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of blinking/flashing, the object is just there, doing nothing.

Comment: What do you mean with "My code (blinking/flashing is not working)"? What does it do instead of working? Have you checked if it gets executed? Does it throw an error?

Comment: You know what, when I first saw the image I thought you meant make the eyes close and open again. Then I saw the code.

Comment: I specifically said I did not literally want it to blink, but to flash. This is not a sprite. There is no alpha (yet). Somebody rewrote my entire post, including adding details that aren't in my project. I think they were trying to help, but they really went overboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you want `Blink` to be executed as a coroutine. But you are executing it directly.

If you call an IEnumerator method directly, you receive an [`IEnumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.8) object which you could then use to run that method from one `yield return` statement to the next by repeatedly calling [`MoveNext()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=netframework-4.8) on it. That means you could, if you wouldn't discard that IEnumerator object.

But what you likely want to do instead is make Unity use that IEnumerator to process a coroutine, like this:

```
StartCoroutine(Blink(itemClone));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `Blink` you are discarding its return value:

```
Blink(itemClone);
```

You do not want to do that. I believe you want to call [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) on it.

> the turd is destroyed the moment the lid starts to come down again

Well, you are calling `Destroy` right after:

```
Blink(itemClone);
Destroy(itemClone, 0.8f);
```

If it is meant to be a continuation of the coroutine (which makes sense) then the easiest solution is to make it part of the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You write in your code, "Blink(itemClone), but how does this start the coroutine?  In my knowledge, you need to have "StartCoroutine("Blink")"  Also, the Destroy function needs to be inside the coroutine or it will be destroyed before the coroutine is finished.  I realize that theraot has already said that, but I was just wondering why his answer hasn't been marked as an answer that worked?

Comment: Sometimes users aren't able to validate working answers right away. It can sometimes take days or even longer for a question-asker to come back and accept an answer that worked for them. Sometimes they forget entirely, and that's OK — we can still upvote answers that work for us, even if the original asker doesn't validate them. There's no need to repeat an answer just because it doesn't have a checkmark, so I'd recommend posting a new answer only if you have a different solution to offer

Comment: I also said this, but it got deleted by moderators: My computer was overheating when I posted and I am getting it repaired. I am on a different computer without my project files right now. The poop emoji is NOT a sprite; I modeled it (lovingly) by hand <3 I will try this solution ASAP and greatly appreciate how knowledgeable and helpful you all have been. I upvoted both answers myself the next morning. Please have faith.

Comment: alright, sorry for the repeat.  Thanks for being responsive, I appreciate that.

Comment: By the way, I like your artwork. :)